# How to find location accuracy?

Tags: android, gps, location, google-api-client

How do I find the location accuracy of an android device running android 8 and below.

```
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);
```

I know there's a `locationRequest.getPriority()` method, but don't know how to use it. I need to find if the location is on device only mode at first before executing the above snippet.
can you please demonstrate a way to find the location accuracy?

I want to know if the location is on High Accuracy or on Battery saver or on Device only mode

Comment: Use `location.getAccuracy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);` and if the appropriate permissions are set on the `AndroidManifest` and if the user has chosen to provide the app with those permissions and if the device has GPS and Network connection, then by god's grace, you have the best location accuracy. About how much accurate your location data is, you can refer to the table below.

[image: Android Location Sensors]

Further Reading: [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location)

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i want to know the location accuracy first, before setting it to high using the setPriority() method

Comment: @AruN you can check location accuracy only after receiving location update not before that.

Comment: @akshay_shahane i've updated the question please recheck. i require the location mode, not accuracy, sorry dude.

Answer (score 0):

Location is within that radius of the measured point in meters.  if Location.getAccuracy returns 10, then there's a 68% chance the true location of the device is within 10 meters of the reported coordinates.

Using this code to get accuracy in meter.

`location.getAccuracy()` //this code getting accuracy in meter.

Here the official document from android.
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()]

If this location does not have a horizontal accuracy, then 0.0 is returned.

Comment: also if location.getAccuracy reutrns zero means location has no accuracy

Comment: @akshay_shahane  If this location does not have a horizontal accuracy, then 0.0 is returned.